# React Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React.js and I have an app that communicates with a server written in Python. I use **`useEffect`** to continuously update the information coming from the server But I'm getting the 'Maximum update depth exceeded' error. This is my code:

```
const address = "http://localhost:4010"
const socket = io(address);

function App() {

  const [MenuState, setMenuState] = useState("/")

  const [UIinputs, setUIinputs] = useState({
    progressState: "stop"
  });

  const [UIoutputs, setUIoutputs] = useState({
    deliveredEnergy: 0,
    estTime: "00:00:00",
    estCost: 0,
    soc: 75,
    chargerState: 4,
    currentPower: 0,
    progressState: 2,
    current: 0,
    voltage: 5,
    carID: "a",
    debug: [{}, {}]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit('UIinputs', UIinputs)
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [UIinputs])

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('UIoutputs', (data) => {
      setUIoutputs(UIoutputs => ({
        ...UIoutputs,
        deliveredEnergy: data.deliveredEnergy,
        estTime: data.estTime,
        soc: data.soc,
        chargerState: data.chargerState,
        currentPower: data.currentPower,
        progressState: data.progressState,
        current: data.current,
        carID: data.carID,
        voltage: data.voltage,
        debug: data.debug,
      }));
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [UIoutputs])

  return (

    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className='app-container'>
        <div className='top-bar'>
          <Header />
          <BackButton
            MenuState={MenuState}
            setMenuState={setMenuState} />
          <ScanQR />
        </div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={
            <Menu
              UIoutputs={UIoutputs}
              setMenuState={setMenuState} />}>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/profile' element={
            <Profile
              UIoutputs={UIoutputs} />}>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/station" element={
            <Charger
              UIinputs={UIinputs}
              setUIinputs={setUIinputs}
              UIoutputs={UIoutputs}
              setUIoutputs={setUIoutputs} />}>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dev" element={
            <Dev
              UIoutputs={UIoutputs} />}>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
        <BottomBar />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update the UIoutputs state inside the useEffect, it triggers a re-render, which in turn causes the useEffect to run again, creating an infinite loop of state updates and re-renders. To fix this issue, you need to ensure that you only update the state when necessary and avoid causing unnecessary re-renders.

so remove the dependency like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('UIoutputs', (data) => {
      setUIoutputs(UIoutputs => ({
        ...UIoutputs,
        deliveredEnergy: data.deliveredEnergy,
        estTime: data.estTime,
        soc: data.soc,
        chargerState: data.chargerState,
        currentPower: data.currentPower,
        progressState: data.progressState,
        current: data.current,
        carID: data.carID,
        voltage: data.voltage,
        debug: data.debug,
      }));
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])
```